# Move the navigation buttons in nautilus to the left in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I move Nautilus' navigation buttons to the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78362/how-do-i-move-nautilus-navigation-buttons-to-the-left)

Can the "navigation buttons" in nautilus 3 be moved to the left (forward and back). I just find them impractical and confusing on the right.

This is nautilus looks by default:

[image: Navigation buttons on the far left]

I would like to move the forward and back buttons to the left of the "location bar". The search button could be left there. Is it possible?