# How do I move Nautilus' navigation buttons to the left?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

Can the "navigation buttons" (forward and back) in nautilus 3 be moved to the left? I just find them impractical and confusing on the right. This is nautilus looks by default:

[image]

I would like to move the forward and back buttons to the left of the "location bar". The search button could be left there. Is it possible?

**Edit:** I posted this as as a bug to the Gnome developers. If you also feel the toolbar should be customizable, suscribe to the bug report in the following link:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=664311

Comment: Three people have already fallen into the trap but please note: we're not talking about the window buttons, rather back, forward, up, search, etc

Answer (score 5):

At the moment there is not solution for this issue, its not a theme related setting that can be changed easily.

If you feel this is greatly affecting you, you may report a bug and suggest the change or the lack of that kind of settings [directly to the gnome developers](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/).

Has an option you can try to use another file manager that has the navigation buttons on the left side, I recommend you `marlin` the ElementaryOS file manager.

[image]

Bar can be customized

[image]

You can install it by adding the `marlin` official PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily/daily && sudo apt-get update
```

Install `marlin` using this command

```
sudo apt-get install marlin
```

After that launch in your dash or by pressing AltF2 and typing `marlin`.

Be aware that `marlin` is still under development and should be used with some caution.

Comment: To the phantom downvoters: This is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I'll contact the GNOME developers, but int he meantime I'll just stick to nautilus. I knew about marlin but since its still in development I prefer not to use it to avoid any problems. Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you do drop a link, maybe more people would like to subscribe to it making your request / bug report more visible.

Comment: Link's been added to the original post, I would of posted it before but I couldn't find time to do so.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

nyteryder79 figured it out and posted his instructions in this [forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1889030):

> It's really easy to do, and I've got the easy Terminal instructions
>   below. BTW, the version of Nautilus current as of this post is 3.2.1.
>   You will probably need to do this any time Nautilus gets updated
>   through Update Manager. The exact line number of the code that needs
>   to change may vary as well. If this is the case, just use find as I
>   instruct below.
>
> Warning: I am not a professional and am not responsible for anything
>   going wrong. These instructions are simply a guide for how I
>   personally managed to fix this annoyance. Use at your own risk.
>
> First off, you may need to enable the "Source code" repository. To do
>   this in Ubuntu, press the Super/Windows key and type "Source". Open
>   the "Software Sources" application from the results. Check the box
>   before "Source code", then click close.
>
> From Terminal:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/Desktop/nautilus-mod
> cd ~/Desktop/nautilus-mod
> sudo apt-get update
> apt-get source nautilus
> sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
> cd ~/Desktop/nautilus-mod/nautilus-3*
> ```
>
> `gedit src/nautilus-toolbar.c`
>
> Now, scroll down to line 132 or do a "find" for
>
> gtk_toolbar_insert (GTK_TOOLBAR (self->priv->toolbar), > item, 0)
>
> and change the `0` to a `2`. So change the original line
>
> from:
>
> ```
> gtk_toolbar_insert (GTK_TOOLBAR (self->priv->toolbar), item,> 0);
> ```
>
> To
>
> ```
> gtk_toolbar_insert (GTK_TOOLBAR (self->priv->toolbar), item,> 2);
> ```
>
> When you're done, click save and close Gedit.
>
> Back in Terminal, run the following:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> sudo killall nautilus
> sudo make install
> nautilus &
> ```
>
> At this point, I would actually recommend logging out and
>   back in or just restarting.
>
> To undo the changes and revert back to stock Nautilus, you can either
>   change the "2" back to a "0", re-make and re-install, or you can
>   simply run:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus
> ```
>
> You might want to remove the required dev packages also, but be careful not to remove
>   something that may have already been there and is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[By far the easiest answer](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/move-title-bar-control-buttons-to-the-right-or-left-even-add-a-spacer-in-ubuntugnome/):

```
gconftool-2 -t str --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout "menu:minimize,maximize,close"
```

Comment: I think he's asking how to move the navigation arrows to the left. Not the window controls.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Ubuntu Forums post which details how to achieve what you want;

[How To Move Nautilus 3+ Back & Forward Buttons to the Left of the Location Bar](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11501676#post11501676)

Essentially follow these steps

> First off, you may need to enable the "Source code" repository. To do
>   this in Ubuntu, press the Super/Windows key and type "Source". Open
>   the "Software Sources" application from the results. Check the box
>   before "Source code", then click close.
>
> `mkdir ~/Desktop/nautilus-mod`
>
> `cd ~/Desktop/nautilus-mod`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `apt-get source nautilus`
>
> `sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus`
>
> `cd ~/Desktop/nautilus-mod/nautilus-3*`
>
> `gedit src/nautilus-toolbar.c`
>
> Now, scroll down to line 132 or do a "find" for "gtk_toolbar_insert
>   (GTK_TOOLBAR (self->priv->toolbar), item, 0)" and change the "0" to a
>   "2".
>
> So change the original line from: `gtk_toolbar_insert (GTK_TOOLBAR
>   (self->priv->toolbar), item, 0);`
>
> To: `gtk_toolbar_insert (GTK_TOOLBAR (self->priv->toolbar), item, 2);`
>
> When you're done, click save and close Gedit.
>
> Back in Terminal, run the following:
>
> `./configure --prefix=/usr`
>
> `make`
>
> `sudo killall nautilus`
>
> `sudo make install`
>
> `nautilus &`
>
> At this point, I would actually recommend logging out and back in or
>   just restarting.
>
> To undo the changes and revert back to stock Nautilus, you can either
>   change the "2" back to a "0", re-make and re-install, or you can
>   simply run:
>
> `sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus`

At all times remember the authors disclaimer;

***Warning: I am not a professional and am not responsible for anything going wrong. These instructions are simply a guide for how I personally managed to fix this annoyance. Use at your own risk.***

Answer (score -6):

Open your Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Run gconf:

```
gconf-editor
```

Go to “apps/metacity/general/”. Find “button_layout” and update the value to:

```
menu:minimize,maximize,close
```

Save, logout and login. Voila !